# Trying to get while loop to work which breaks when a symbol is inputted rather than a character

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to code a program that performs the task until "*" is entered. Here is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    char character;
    if (character != "*") {
        scanf("%c", &character);
        printf("ascii: %d\n", character);
    }
    else{ 
        printf("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

But when I run it and type "*" it doesn't print goodbye it just prints the normal ASCII value. I'm still new to C.

Comment: At the time of `if (character != "*") {` -- what is the value of `character`??

Comment: C or C++? Choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
character != "*"
```

will be

```
character != '*'
```

But moreover you were working with unintialized value. You should initialize it before you do the comparison.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    char character;
    if(scanf("%c", &character) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if( character != '*'){
        printf("ascii: %d\n", character);
    }
    else {
        printf("Goodbye");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first `if` checks whether the input using `scanf` is successful or not. This will check whether a character is input and that is assigned to `character` or not. For input like `1234` it will get `1` as input and then rest will be kept in stdin. `scanf` parses `stdin` for the character. The moment it gets it - it will stop, consumed the input here `1` and leave everything else in the `stdin`.

Also enable all compiler warnings

```
gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c
```

Also earlier you were comparing an address with an ascii value. `"a"` is different from `'a'`. Literal strings are basically arrays which decayed into pointer to the first element of the array which is `'a'`. You can try this and it would work.(not good practice).

```
if( character != "*"[0]){
```

`"*"[0]` is basically accessing the 0-th element which is `'a'`.

#### Op asked how the input will fail?

If it gets `EOF` in input then it will fail.(one of the way)

```
>>> touch emptyfile.txt
>>> gcc -Wall -Werror prog.c
>>> ./a.out < emptyfile.txt
Error in input
```

Or simply doing this

```
>>> gcc -Wall -Werror prog.c
>>> ./a.out
<Press Ctrl-D>
```